# How to let the links on facebook not editable

Tags: facebook, youtube

I'm having a problem a few days. I have a website and would like to try to share on Facebook, the title and image to become non-editable, as is the youtube.

They could inform me how to "fix" these meta tags to make them non-editable?

[image]

Comment: How to stop it like youtube does?

Comment: the youtube link is not possible to edit, I want to leave my non-editable link too!

Comment: I don't believe that's possible to do.